# Difference between javascript depending on underlying OS / reactJs

Tags: javascript, ubuntu, reactjs

So I have the weirdest issue that I can't quite figure out (or didn't know existed) between my local environment and production server.

My local environment runs windows, and my production server is a digital ocean ubuntu distro. My javascript can compare to this:

I have this construction (simplified):

```
var myClass = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function(){
        return { number: 1 };
    },
    doSomething: function(numIn){
        this.setState({ number: this.state.number + numIn });
    },
    render: function(){
        return(
            <div>{this.state.number}</div>  
        );
    }
});
```

Lets assume myClass.doSomething is called with `1`, so the expected state would be 1+1 = 2. On my local environment (windows) it will output what you would expect:

```
<div> {this.state.number} </div> => <div>2</div>
```

All good an dandy. On my ubuntu distro it's a bit funky though, it will concatinate it instead, so same input would yield:

```
<div>12</div>
```

Now I get that I can use parseInt, or parseFloat around every single addition (which I guess I should do anyway), but it clutters the code and is annoying. That aside, I don't understand why the underlying OS has anything to do with this, the javascript surely run in the clients browser?

As I'm writing this, it hits me that it might be my response from the backend, which initially returns the number as a JSON. Could the interpretation of this value be different based on OS? so on ubuntu it would be a string initially, and hence javascript would see string + number = string?

Comment: Where does the ``` originate? Can you trace it back to, say, a file or a database? Is it stored in the same form in both environments?

Comment: Why this happens, I can't say for certain but it's fairly irrelevant. Dynamic typing means that if you want to specify a type and ensure an operation performs how you want, it really is crucial to use the conversion functions such as `parseInt` even if it is ugly. That said, where is `numIn` coming from?

Comment: numIn originates from a database where it's defined as a bigInt. The state is originally populated by an ajax request, where the response is this:

{ number: "1" } Edit: that was a lie, my $arr -> json converter takes the int and smashes quotes on it, without me telling it to. I guess that is the origin.  Still, I don't get how this is different based on underlying os?

Comment: @Dennis Does the server send back a quoted or non-quoted version differently in the JSON response on each OS? Perhaps it has something to do with the JSON library used on the server (e.g. compiling it on one OS makes it do something different), or something odd in a database driver?

Comment: @BinaryMuse Right you are. The windows one returns it unquoted as a number. I use Laravel 5.0 for backend with it's response()->json(); method, so I will have to investigate there. Thanks for all the help guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this was to ensure always using the respective parse versions of primitives in javascript, as windows and linux returns these values differently (with or without quotes).